# Configure Log.io to monitor all the log files inside a folder

Tags: node.js, logging

I want [Log.io](http://logio.org/) harvester to detect a new log file inside a folder and automatically starts monitoring it.

That is, I could configure the harvester (`~/.log.io/harvester.conf`) as follows, and add log files to that folder (`~/my_logs/`) as I go, and they will appear on the server immediately.

```
exports.config = {
    nodeName: "application_server",
    logStreams: {
      my_logs: [
        "~/my_logs/*"
      ]
    },
    server: {
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      port: 28777
    }
  }
```

I didn't have any luck finding anything on that matter so far.

Comment: Found any workaround to this?

Comment: @AnandNadar No. That's the only thing preventing me from using Log.io

Comment: So far I have come across https://github.com/NarrativeScience/Log.io/issues/162 that can help assign a function to the file list. Then I am thinking of using Consul & Consul Template to update the configuration dynamically and restart the service automatically when  a new log is added. Not really a solution but is more of a workaround.